# How do I get IntelliJ's Typescript assistance to resolve Angular2 installed from a WebJAR?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, typescript, angular, sbt

I'm using the [`sbt-typescript`](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/sbt-typescript) plugin to let me use Typescript assets in Play. I've modeled my project layout on [the example one](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript), but something like `import {Injectable} from "angular2/core"` gives me a red underline for `TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'`. In fact, Angular 2 is in `target/web/node-modules/main/webjars/angular2`.

Play itself compiles the `.ts` file without a problem.

What do I need to configure in IntelliJ to get it looking in the same place as `sbt` for `angular2`?